# Copying a working app and removing and renaming things to make a new app?

Tags: iphone, project, rename, viewcontroller

I now have a bunch of finished apps. This new app that I'm making has the same structure, a couple tabs less. Can I save time by copying the project folder and somehow 'unhook it' from the previous paths etc, and rename viewcontroller names etc?

What steps do I take to ensure it's entirely decoupled from the finished app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a "safe" way could be this:

you can create a new project in xcode and open the old project, then drag and drop files/class/resources directly in xCode from the old project to the new one, be sure to select the "copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" button... xCode will copy all files in the new project folder for you...

Comment: +1 I will mark this as answer - it's already the way I import individual classes for reuse, of course. But I was hoping for a more efficient way for these very similar apps (there are often quite a few resources so the manual labor is not negligible), but by reading other questions about similar problems I have a decent workflow. Thanks!